# How to set the Boolean value into GridView Check boxes in C#?

Tags: asp.net

How to set the Boolean value into GridView Check boxes in C#?

This is my code simply

```
static List<bool> bh = new List<bool>(6);

dt.Columns.Add("Hold");
dr["Hold"] = rem[x].Hold;

bh.Add(Convert.Toboolean((string)dr["Hold"]));
```

gridview codes

```
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RemitID" HeaderText="RemitID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TransferedDate" HeaderText="TransferedDate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ValueDate" HeaderText="ValueDate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RemitterName" HeaderText="RemitterName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BenificiaryName" HeaderText="BenificiaryName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AccountNo" HeaderText="AccountNo" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Reference" HeaderText="Reference" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Hold" HeaderText="Hold" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Reject" HeaderText="Reject" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Delete" HeaderText="Delete" />
        </Columns>
```

here i am using List<> because have to add set of datas. No runtime errors are occur but checkboxes not showing the values.. Thank you !

Comment: <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Hold" HeaderText="Hold" />

Comment: Code is missing here. You add the column to the dt (but you don't set it to be boolean). You set something in dr (datareader???), and you add the 7th item to a list?

Comment: dt.Columns.Add("Hold",typeof(bool)); now I have changed like this.. dr means  DataRow dr = dt.NewRow(); // Create new Row   , but still same problem .. those check boxes cannot be edit too..

Comment: @FazalMohamed plz provide your code properly and edit your question for that instead of commenting that code.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I missed to add dt.Rows.Add(bh[i]); .. Now check boxes showing the values.. I cannot edit by on the grid view, How it will be possible?